# How to check domain name availability using AWS Route 53 API with JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-route53

I wanna check the domain name availability on AWS from Spring boot (JAVA).

So I would need to call AWS API to get the response, to check whether it is available or not.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JAVA SDK to call the [CheckDomainAvailabilityRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53domains/AmazonRoute53DomainsClient.html#checkDomainAvailability-com.amazonaws.services.route53domains.model.CheckDomainAvailabilityRequest-) function for the AmazonRoute53DomainsClient.

The response will simply return the availability of that domain via the Amazon Route 53 domains API.

According to the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53domains/check-domain-availability.html) it can return one of the following statues:

Valid values:

- AVAILABLE: The domain name is available.
- AVAILABLE_RESERVED: The domain name is reserved under specific conditions.
- AVAILABLE_PREORDER: The domain name is available and can be preordered.
- DONT_KNOW: The TLD registry didn't reply with a definitive answer about whether the domain name is available. Route 53 can return this response for a variety of reasons, for example, the registry is performing maintenance. Try again later.
- PENDING: The TLD registry didn't return a response in the expected amount of time. When the response is delayed, it usually takes just a few extra seconds. You can resubmit the request immediately.
- RESERVED: The domain name has been reserved for another person or organization.
- UNAVAILABLE: The domain name is not available.
- UNAVAILABLE_PREMIUM: The domain name is not available.
- UNAVAILABLE_RESTRICTED: The domain name is forbidden.

Comment: I'm getting `java.net.UnknownHostException: route53domains.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` error

Comment: Use the region of us-east-1